# Can you define headers in Karate tests?

Tags: karate

The background of every Karate test I have looks like this:

```
Background:
    * url baseUrl
    * header key = "123456789"
```

Is there a way to make it cleaner by defining the header I am passing for every test?

Comment: you should really read the documentation, it will save you a lot of time: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#configure-headers